# UIAlertController keeps disappearing automatically

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

So I have a UIAlertController created with the following code:

```
let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You have made  changes to \(workoutTemplate!.name). Do you wish to overwrite these changes?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

            alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes, Overwrite", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in

                //... some code

            }))

            alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No, Rename", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in

                   //..some more code                     
            }))

self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I've set up the Alert controller to show up on the press of a button, however the alert keeps disappearing automatically :

[image]

EDIT: Found the problem! It was a silly oversight on my part. The code above was in a switch. Immediately after the switch, I had a `self.dismissViewController()` call. I had left out an `else` statement and the VC tried to dismiss itself right after presenting the AlertController. However, since the AlertController was at the top of the navigation stack at the time of this call, it got dismissed.

Comment: Your code is working fine.There may be another problem.

Comment: what type of action is calling this code, is it button touchUpInside?

Comment: Yes, it is a touch up inside.

Comment: I had same issue. Please put code to resolve this issue.